# Scheduled function not being called

Tags: scala, akka

Scheduling a function to be run every X seconds using Scala, this is what works for me :

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Driver {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

   val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("system")
   system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 1 seconds)(println("beep"))

  }
}
```

This implementation :

```
object Driver {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val t = new java.util.Timer()
    val task = new java.util.TimerTask {
      def run() = println("Beep!")
    }

    t.schedule(task, 1000L, 1000L)
    task.cancel()
  }
}
```

And

```
import java.util.concurrent._

object Driver {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val ex = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1)

    val task = new Runnable {
      def run() = println("Beep!")
    }

    val f = ex.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    f.cancel(false)

  }
}
```

Do not run. They just hang and no output is displayed. What could be causing this ? If I debug the code then it appears to run sometimes, so this is environment related issue ?

Comment: Well... May be I am wrong... but I think you are cancelling the task before it gets scheduled. Remove that `task.cancel` line and change your `run` def - `val task = new java.util.TimerTask { def run() = { println("Beep!"); this.cancel( false ); } }`

Comment: Similar goes for the third one.

Comment: And after reading @kosii I am ever more sure about me being wrong. :)

Comment: @Sarvesh Kumar Singh but your suggestions appear to work....

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh you are right in this: "you are cancelling the task before it gets scheduled"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it will better not use interface Runnable and use only akka with scala for your job. You must use Cancellable for scheduling task an easy and correct way using actors is like this

From the akka documentation follow like this

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.util.duration._

    //Schedules to send the "foo"-message to the testActor after 50ms
    system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(50 milliseconds, testActor, "foo")

//Schedules a function to be executed (send the current time) to the testActor after 50ms
system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(50 milliseconds) {
  testActor ! System.currentTimeMillis
}

val Tick = "tick"
val tickActor = system.actorOf(Props(new Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Tick ⇒ //write here the function you want to execute
  }
}))


//This will schedule to send the Tick-message
//to the tickActor after 0ms repeating every 50ms
val cancellable =
  system.scheduler.schedule(0 milliseconds,
    50 milliseconds,
    tickActor,
    Tick)

//This cancels further Ticks to be sent
cancellable.cancel()
```

this is a complete example that works:

using scala 2.11.6 and akka 2.3.8

```
package org.example

import akka.actor.{ ActorSystem, Props, Actor }

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps

/**
 * Created by anquegi on 10/04/15.
 */
object ScheduledTaskScala extends App {

  //Use the system's dispatcher as ExecutionContext
  import system.dispatcher

  val system = ActorSystem.create("sheduledtask");

  val Tick = "tick"
  val tickActor = system.actorOf(Props(new Actor {
    def receive = {
      case Tick ⇒ { Thread.sleep(1000); println("I'm executing a task"); }
    }
  }))

  //This will schedule to send the Tick-message
  //to the tickActor after 0ms repeating every 2 s
  val cancellable =
    system.scheduler.schedule(0 milliseconds,
      2 seconds,
      tickActor,
      Tick)

  Thread.sleep(10000)

  cancellable.cancel()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `java.util.Timer`'s scheduler thread does not run as a daemon thread, so it may keep the application from terminating. So you should either

1. call `t.cancel()`, or
2. create your timer with `isDaemon` set true: 
   `new java.util.Timer(true)`

As for the second example, it's basically the same underlying problem, you should call `ex.shutdown()` to keep your application hanging.

Comment: running as daemon appears to shutdown JVM and no tasks are started

Comment: In this case you still can use `t.cancel()`. In any case, it's your job to correctly synchronize the shutdown of different threads or threadpools.